# How to put a file to queue by using rfhutil and mq?

Tags: ascii, ibm-mq, delimiter, mq

I think title is confusing. I try to explain it in detail. 
I have a big xml file that contains a lot of messages for queue. The structure looks like: <'objects'><...>.....<...><'/objects'>. It's an array of objects tags and one item of objects is a message. I want to put this file that should be broken into a separate messages into queue(mq) by using rfhutil.
I know it's possible but I'm confused about delimiter. The whole menu looks puzzled. 
Is anyone using rfhutil and mq? Maybe you have a guide for that. I couldn't find any information about rfhutil. 
I hope I explained well.[there is a pic of rfhutil menu. load Q](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPsNl.png)

Comment: Can you edit your question and post a sample off the the data showing 2 objects.

Comment: To put a message to a queue, you need to save it in a file, then open the file in rfhutil and then write queue. But rfhutil won't break you large message into samller ones, it cannot parse your custom XML. The load q option can put multiple messages, but the input file needs to be in a rfhutil specific format.

Answer (score 1):

"Load Q" option is used to send all messages from file which was previously created with "Save Q" option. It will not properly parse your custom xml. Even if you format xml in a way that is parsable by custom delimiter, xml still contains only message payload and lacks message headers.

However rfhutil is part of lagerger [IH03 SupportPack](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24000637) and there you will find:

1. additional software to send multiple custom messages like mqput
2. a manual how to do it (ih03.doc)

Simplest "out of head" solution would be to split xml in multiple smaller files and than send them all with one mqput2 command.

Comment: The link to the support pack is no longer valid. The utility can now be found on it's github page:https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-rfhutil